# Where I can download angular 2

Tags: angular

I want download Angular 2 stable version.
So when I search in Google and watch some sites they pass me into this URL.

```
https://github.com/angular/quickstart
```

But when I type

> ng -v

to watch my Angular app information tell me your app version is 4 
Is this URL is true or note.
if is note true please send a good URL

Comment: Uh, the current version is Angular 6. You're asking the angular equivalent of "where can I get Windows 98?" (you can't.) The final version of 2 was released in 2016. Why do you need this particular version?

Comment: The url is for the quickstart project, not angular 2. If you read the docs on that quickstart repo it states that it's deprecated and the preferred method of getting started is to use the angular-cli. Use npm or your favorite package manager to download the angular of your choice, though angular 5 is current stable.

Comment: Ng command is for angular cli

Comment: The provided url is just a quickstart, a bunch of folders that set up a project for you. It's obvious that, for you, is not clear what Angular is and how to use it, so I think you may start from Angular documentation and you'll understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply misunderstood the concept behind developing angular projects.

When you've downloaded the above mentioned project, you'll find a file named **package.json**. It contains, among other things, the entire set of packages you want/have to use throughout your project. And this is where you can adjust your angular version. Here is an example of how it looks like. You'll find entries with angular 2 versions.

```
// ...

"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
  "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
  "rxjs": "^5.4.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/cli": "1.2.4",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
  "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",

// ...
```

So, open your package.json, adjust the version to what suites your needs and save the file.

Then make sure that you are in the project path and run the command

```
npm install
```

Now NPM will download the preconfigured angular version you set in package.json. That's the way it goes.

But please be aware of the fact that you'll always have a lot of dependencies. It might be that you will face error messages during the installation because other packages aren't capable working with the latest angular version. You have to adjust them step by step until all versions fit together. There's no way around though.